# JavaScript performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

Want to ask which one of this functions more effective?

```
#1
function moveNode (node) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        node.style.top = (node.offsetTop+2) + 'px';
        moveNode(node);
    },50);
}

#2
function moveNode (node, distance) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        node.style.top = (distance) + 'px';
        moveNode(node,distance+2);
    },50);
}
```

In first function we are fetching `node.offsetTop` property every call, but remember less data. In second function we can pass `node.offsetTop` property as`distance` argument only one time, but remember it from call to call. So i don't know which way is more effective. Assume that this function will be called many times with different `node` arguments (in `setInterval` for example)

Comment: There is no recursion in your code snippets. The performance difference is negligible, but the one with ```distance``` is more readable for sure.

Comment: @tevemadar so when inner function starts,program forget about parent function?

Comment: There will be one closure kept at a time (the inner function accesses ```node``` and in case of the second variant, ```distance```), but it does not make the control flow recursive. Recursion would mean that control at least theoretically returns to ```moveNode```, after running it a second, third, etc. time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetching `offsetTop` might require a reflow and can be *very* slow. Also it accesses the native DOM, which is slower than a JS property access as well. The second one will be much more efficient. In comparison, the memory requirements for storing one more variable value in the closure are absolutely negligible.